# Using Laravel language variables in js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am using multiple languages in Laravel. I am getting the results of some data via Javascript files.
My problem is that I need to convert the results from javascript to language. For this reason, I need to define language variables in javascript.

My language variables are like this;

```
{{ __('folder/folder.file') }}
```

sample javascript content

```
if (response == 0) {
    e.innerHTML = `You have received no orders in the last 90 days.`;
} else {
    e.innerHTML = `{{ __('folder/folder.file') }}`;
}
```

As you can see I didn't define the `{{ __('folder/folder.file') }}` language variables but it didn't work.
How can I use it correctly here?

Comment: Assign ```{{ __('folder/folder.file') }}``` to a JS variable and just  reference to it.

Comment: Are you using external js or internal js?

Comment: i am using external Js file.

Comment: Why not write the code internally?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `PHP` variable in the `script` tag inside the `blade` template your code is working well. But for external JS:

#### Use PHP and Laravel methods in Javascript

Define your language variable:**( above your js code )**

```
<script>    
    var myVar = {!! __('folder/folder.file') !!};
</script>
```

or use `@JSON` blade directive for objects and arrays :

```
var myVar = @json($array);
```

Then use `myVar` in your JS scripts

for your example :

```
if (response == 0) {
    e.innerHTML = `You have received no orders in the last 90 days.`;
} else {
    e.innerHTML = myVar;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I tried these but it didn't work. I am using external Js file.

Comment: @Ontrable Answer updated, please re-read and make sure declare the  variable in your blade template (not external) and above your main js source.

Comment: I think the problem is the Js file. It doesn't read because I can't write it between the ` ` quotes. The js file content continues from KTCardsWidgetWeekly = { ..

Answer (score 0):

You can't *directly* access PHP variables or functions in JavaScript, since when the Browser delivers contents of the requested URL to the client, it doesn't deliver PHP code but HTML (from your routes/web.php) or JSON (from your routes/api.php) depending on the case.

So, you need a way to access your translation variables some way or another (one of these options):

1. Make resources/lang publically accessable and use JSON files, that can be requested via `fetch()`
2. Make an endpoint in your routes/api.php to deliver your translations
3. `echo` them into your JS using blade as @Royal_MGH suggested